# Django password form field doesn't look like other field. How can i fix it?

Tags: python, django

Although I specify a class in forms.py, the password fields do not appear as regular as the others. What is the reason for this and how can I fix it.

forms.py

```
class registerForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUserModel
        fields=("first_name","last_name","email","phone_number","password1","password2")
        widgets = {
            "first_name" : TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control floating"}),
            "last_name" : TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control floating"}),
            "email" : EmailInput(attrs={"class":"form-control floating","type":"email"}),
            "phone_number" : TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control floating"}),
            "password1" : PasswordInput(attrs={"class":"form-control floating"}),
            "password2" : PasswordInput(attrs={"class":"form-control floating"}),
        }
```

[image: In my template form looks like this]
In my template form looks like this

Comment: can you share template code??

Comment: You mean - You want to hide `password instructions` ?

Comment: Can you describe the expected behaviour?